# How to display employee status day wise in a month

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Below is my table structure and data.

```
EMPLID  EMPL_RCD    EFFDT   Eff_SEQ HR_STATUS   PER_ORG
722243  0         21-Nov-18 0   A            CWR
722243  0         15-May-19 0   A            CWR
722243  0         20-May-19 0   I            CWR
722243  1         20-May-19 0   A            EMP
120707  1         14-May-19 0   A            EMP
120707  0         29-May-19 0   I            EMP
120707  1         29-May-19 0   I            EMP
120707  2         29-May-19 0   A            CWR
```

when I pass month start date and end date in my query('01-MAY-2019' AND '31-MAY-2019') the query should display the data like below for `EMPLID` 722243  and 120707.

```
EMPLID               Date               PER_ORG  HR_STATUS
---------------------------------------------------------
722243                01-MAY-19      CWR          A
722243                02-MAY-19      CWR          A
722243                03-MAY-19      CWR          A
722243                04-MAY-19      CWR          A
```

same should display until  19-MAY-19

```
722243                19-MAY-19      CWR           A
120707                29-MAY-19      CWR           A
120707                30-MAY-19      CWR           A
120707                31-MAY-19      CWR           A
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: Why does your expected output not have any rows for the second user between 1st and 28th may? Why does your output stop for the first user on 19th May when the last entry for them in the table is the 20th May? Why does the first user stop on the day before its last entry but the second user carries on to the end of the month which is beyond its last entry?

Comment: What is the significance of the `EMPL_RCD`, `HR_STATUS` and `PER_ORG` columns and why does your expected output only have `A`/`CWR` values?

Comment: For first user  is  'I' (inactive ) from 20-May-19. So i want to display until 19-May-19. and second user is active as CWR from 29-May-19, so i want to display the data for second user from 29th May to 31st May.  HR_STATUS is to identify employee active status. A= Active and  I = inactive.PER_ORG is to identify employee type EMP = Employee and CWR = contract employee. EFF_SEQ wale will increase if there are more than one transaction in same day.  EMPL_RCD value will increase when ever employee converted from CWR to Emp and EMP to CWR (0,1,2...)

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, EFFDT, Eff_SEQ, HR_STATUS, PER_ORG ) AS
SELECT 722243, 0, DATE '2018-11-21', 0, 'A', 'CWR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 722243, 0, DATE '2019-05-15', 0, 'A', 'CWR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 722243, 0, DATE '2019-05-20', 0, 'I', 'CWR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 722243, 1, DATE '2019-05-20', 0, 'A', 'EMP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 120707, 1, DATE '2019-05-14', 0, 'A', 'EMP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 120707, 0, DATE '2019-05-29', 0, 'I', 'EMP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 120707, 1, DATE '2019-05-29', 0, 'I', 'EMP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 120707, 2, DATE '2019-05-29', 0, 'A', 'CWR' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**: All `PER_ORG` values:

```sql
WITH bounds ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-05-01', DATE '2019-05-31' FROM DUAL
),
calendar ( dt ) AS (
  SELECT start_date + LEVEL - 1
  FROM   bounds
  CONNECT BY start_date + LEVEL - 1 <= end_date
),
table_name_with_prev_status ( emplid, effdt, hr_status, per_org, prev_hr_status ) AS (
  SELECT EMPLID,
         EFFDT,
         HR_STATUS,
         PER_ORG,
         LAG( HR_STATUS, 1, 'I' )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY EMPLID, PER_ORG ORDER BY EFFDT, EMPL_RCD )
  FROM   table_name
),
statuses ( emplid, effdt, hr_status, per_org ) AS (
  SELECT EMPLID,
         DT,
         COALESCE(
           HR_STATUS,
           LAG( HR_STATUS ) IGNORE NULLS
             OVER ( PARTITION BY EMPLID, PER_ORG ORDER BY DT ),
           LEAD( PREV_HR_STATUS ) IGNORE NULLS
             OVER ( PARTITION BY EMPLID, PER_ORG ORDER BY DT )
         ),
         PER_ORG
  FROM   calendar c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name_with_prev_status t
         PARTITION BY ( t.EMPLID, t.PER_ORG )
         ON ( c.dt = t.effdt )
)
SELECT *
FROM   statuses
WHERE  HR_STATUS = 'A'
ORDER BY emplid, effdt
```

**Output**:

> ```
> EMPLID | EFFDT     | HR_STATUS | PER_ORG
> -----: | :-------- | :-------- | :------
> 120707 | 14-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 15-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 16-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 17-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 18-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 19-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 20-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 21-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 22-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 23-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 24-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 25-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 26-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 27-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 28-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 120707 | 29-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 120707 | 30-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 120707 | 31-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 01-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 02-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 03-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 04-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 05-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 06-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 07-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 08-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 09-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 10-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 11-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 12-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 13-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 14-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 15-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 16-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 17-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 18-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 19-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 20-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 722243 | 21-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 722243 | 22-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 722243 | 23-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 722243 | 24-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 722243 | 25-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 722243 | 26-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 722243 | 27-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 722243 | 28-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 722243 | 29-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 722243 | 30-MAY-19 | A         | EMP    
> 722243 | 31-MAY-19 | A         | EMP
> ```

**Query**: Just `CWR` values:

```sql
WITH bounds ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-05-01', DATE '2019-05-31' FROM DUAL
),
calendar ( dt ) AS (
  SELECT start_date + LEVEL - 1
  FROM   bounds
  CONNECT BY start_date + LEVEL - 1 <= end_date
),
table_name_with_prev_status ( emplid, effdt, hr_status, per_org, prev_hr_status ) AS (
  SELECT EMPLID,
         EFFDT,
         HR_STATUS,
         PER_ORG,
         LAG( HR_STATUS, 1, 'I' )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY EMPLID, PER_ORG ORDER BY EFFDT, EMPL_RCD )
  FROM   table_name
),
statuses ( emplid, effdt, hr_status, per_org ) AS (
  SELECT EMPLID,
         DT,
         COALESCE(
           HR_STATUS,
           LAG( HR_STATUS ) IGNORE NULLS
             OVER ( PARTITION BY EMPLID, PER_ORG ORDER BY DT ),
           LEAD( PREV_HR_STATUS ) IGNORE NULLS
             OVER ( PARTITION BY EMPLID, PER_ORG ORDER BY DT )
         ),
         PER_ORG
  FROM   calendar c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name_with_prev_status t
         PARTITION BY ( t.EMPLID, t.PER_ORG )
         ON ( c.dt = t.effdt )
)
SELECT *
FROM   statuses
WHERE  HR_STATUS = 'A'
AND    PER_ORG   = 'CWR'
ORDER BY emplid, effdt
```

**Output**:

> ```
> EMPLID | EFFDT     | HR_STATUS | PER_ORG
> -----: | :-------- | :-------- | :------
> 120707 | 29-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 120707 | 30-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 120707 | 31-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 01-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 02-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 03-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 04-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 05-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 06-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 07-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 08-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 09-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 10-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 11-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 12-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 13-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 14-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 15-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 16-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 17-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 18-MAY-19 | A         | CWR    
> 722243 | 19-MAY-19 | A         | CWR
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5383f7d5766a7c0e174fe47112152fcd)*

Comment: @Muneendra If the answer has solved your problem then you can accept the answer. If you have follow on questions then you can ask those in a new question; it is not appropriate to try tacking additional parts onto an existing question.